How can I generate an AES secret key using window.crypto in javascript and use it to encrypt the message
I am trying to generate an AES-CBC scratch key to encrypt messages. Here is the code to generate and retrieve the key:
const key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
      name: "AES-CBC",
      length: 256,
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );
const secretKey = await crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', key)

I'm trying to use the resulting secret key to encrypt messages on the https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption
But I see a mistake: Length of secret key should be 32 for 256 bits key size
I tried getting the key in Uint8Array and translating to base64, but it doesn't work for me.
I need to create AES secret key, encrypt the message with it using window.crypto. Later I want to be able to decrypt this message without using window.crypto.
Now I don't understand what I need to do with the Uint8Array that is returned from exportKey

Export the key with format raw instead of jwk. The key is then exported as a 32 bytes ArrayBuffer and can then be Base64 encoded, s. here.

I've tried doing this, but trying to use this key in other places, I get an error that the key is invalid

An AES-256 key is simply a 32 bytes sequence. Why should a Base64 encoded AES key not be usable in other places? You are obviously making something wrong and should explain in more detail what you are doing, s. MCVE.

You should find your answer here :

For encrypt:


encrypt(algorithm, secretKey, data)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

For decrypt:


decrypt(algorithm, secretKey, data)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt
The "algorithm" paramter can be set as an AesCbcParams, see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AesCbcParams
Be careful with the security of your secretKey, you should use that : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey

Please include the relevant information from the links. As it stands now, there is very little information directly in your answer.
